# Pass Customer FormRequest to GET in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm curious is that possible to pass (as type-hinted) of custom class that extends FormRequest to be passed in to action within GET request ?

for example:
at routes/api.php

```
Route::get('/schema', '\App\Http\Controllers\TestController@getSchema');
```

then I have App\Http\Requests\SchemaRequest.php

and at controller, I want get this request from route within GET method.

```
class TestController extends Controller {
    public function getSchema(\App\Http\Requests\SchemaRequest $request) {
        // do other stuff here
    }
}
```

I've tried to look deeper and doing some hack but nothing success yet?

Is that possible?

Any input would be appreciated, and thanks for reading

Comment: What error(s) do you see?

Comment: it is redirected to /, instead of routing to TestController@getSchema

Comment: You want to create a new request class and then use them in your controller?

Comment: @LucasPiazzi yes exactly but using GET route, I need to do some customization within the Request that extends from FormRequest

Comment: @DidinAhmadi is the `authorize()` method returning true in your `SchemaRequest.php`?

Comment: @Tanmay yes, I already return true inside `authorize()`

Comment: @DidinAhmadi Is this route, `/schema` defined inside a middleware group? Maybe `auth:api` or something?

Comment: @Tanmay, no, it is wrote as it is at question, it is just simple route, no use defined middleware at all.

Comment: @DidinAhmadi what happens when you remove the `\App\Http\Requests\SchemaRequest $request` parameter from getSchema() method and do `dd('Hello, I am hit!')` inside the method? Do you see the statement executed when you visit the route?

Comment: @Tanmay yes, it working `dd` statement executed well when custom typehinted request removed, seems Laravel is avoid to inject custom request to action within GET route?

Comment: No, Laravel doesn't discriminate among the http verbs. It should work with GET as well. Could you show us the content of `SchemaRequest.php`?

Comment: @tanmay `SchemaRequest.php` is just blank, it is just newly created and still fresh, I only changed to `authorize()` to return true.

Comment: I am seriously running out of clues here :D What happens when you add these two statements as your method body: `$request = app('\App\Http\Requests\TestRequest');
        dd($request);` and remove the typehinted param?

Comment: Thanks @Tanmay, yeah I spent all day to get this but nothing work :(
I tried your way, still redirected to / (showing Laravel index page), when I removed then add `dd('test')`, its working. Not sure, actually the Idea is to use 1 method to accept multiple method (GET and POST), but both can accept typehinted from custom request.

Answer (score 0):

How about this workaround?

```
Route::get('/schema', 'TestController@getSchema',namespace =>'App\Http\Controller');

class TestController extends Controller {
    public function getSchema(Request $request) {
        // do other stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: that will work seems, but not as I expected. 
the passed request at first param, I expect is should be from customised class that extend FormRequest.

Comment: Not sure but thats how mine work even with customize class. Or maybe you can crrate a middleware for it?